# FFMPEG concat video finished but the video missing

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I was concatenated video with FFMPEG. Here is code:
`ffmpeg -i "concat:video1.webm|video2.webm|video3.webm|video4.webm" -c copy output_video.webm`

After concatenate finished, I play the video but the video display only video1. It missing the video2, video3, video4. Although, The output_video.webm is full size. I don't know why? Please help me, How to fix it?

Thank you so much,
Bien

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because the 'concat protocol' (also called as binary concat) is not supported for 'webm' file format. It is supported for avi, mpeg-ts. Please find the [FFMPEG Concat](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) documentation talks about this in detail.

**Solution:**
As mentioned in above document, you can use the 'concat demuxer' which is more flexible as below:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy output


Where mylist.txt is something like:

# this is a comment
file '/path/to/file1'
file '/path/to/file2'
file '/path/to/file3'
```

Example of combining 2 mp4 files (video1.mp4 and video2.mp4) in current directory.

ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i filelist.txt -c copy output.mp4
```

content of 'filelist.txt'

```
file 'video1.mp4'
file 'video2.mp4'
```

concatenated videos available @ output.mp4

Comment: Thank Arun Kumar, I am using record video from web browser and I am using this command to concat: cd /var/www/html/record/uploads/tmp; ls > filelist.txt; find *.webm | sed 's:\ :\\\ :g'| sed 's/^/file /' > filelist.txt; ffmpeg -f concat -i filelist.txt -c copy /var/www/html/record/uploads/".$filename.".webm; rm -rf *

Comment: When i finished concat the videos. I open the video but it can't display all content. The output video display only one of file1. I was tried merge video with MKVToolNix software at window. It have same problem. The MKVToolNix merge video successfull, but i open the video it can't display all content. The output video display only content of the file1. I don't know why? and How to fix it?

Comment: I guess there is an issue in the above command. The $filename is prepended and appended with extra DOT.  try this 'ffmpeg -f concat -i filelist.txt -c copy /var/www/html/record/uploads/output.webm'. This used to work for me.

Comment: Dear Arun Kumar, I merged videos with ffmpeg, but the output video missing content. Have you finished merge videos with ffmpeg? How to do that for the output video have full content?

Comment: It worked for me. I can see the concatenated output video. I used the command 'ffmpeg -f concat -i filelist.txt -c copy output.mp4'  and 'filelist.txt' has 2 lines. Line1:file 'video1.mp4'  Line2:file 'video2.mp4'