# Concatenating videos using concat demuxer in FFMPEG is finished but video is lost in second video?

Tags: android, kotlin, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg, video-editing

Used concat demuxer in FFMPEG code to concat videos :-

```
cmd = arrayOf("-y", "-f", "concat", "-safe", "0", "-i", textFile!!.path, "-c:v", "libx264", "-crf", "23", "-preset", "ultrafast", "-c:a", "copy", outputFile.path)
```

After concatenate finished, the video one played correctly has both audio & video but video two - video is missing has only audio. Output file has size & time duration including two videos.

The textFile contains :-

```
file '/path/to/file1'
file '/path/to/file2'
```

Used `absolutePath` for two mp4 video files.

Tryed this [FFMPEG concat video finished but the video missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43536929/ffmpeg-concat-video-finished-but-the-video-missing). But no solution to my problem.

Anything I am missing in the command.

Comment: Show complete output of `ffmpeg -i file1 -i file2`.

Comment: @llogan Show complete output of what. Unable to understand. Can you explain it?

Comment: To concatenate properly each input must have the same attributes. I suspect that they differ. To verify this I wanted to see information about each input and information about your ffmpeg version and configuration. Running the command I provided will supply this information which is required for me to give you a turn-key answer that you can copy and paste.

Comment: Each video file is 03:59 duration with nearly 20 MB in size. FFMPEG version is 0.3.2. Any other information you needed?

Comment: Does the width, height, pixel format, timescale, H.264 profile, timebase, audio channel layout, audio sample rate, video formats, audio format, number of streams match?